# How to chain two separate camel routes together for throttling

Tags: apache-camel

I have two separate routes running in an application and I want to control the total amount of work in flight across the entire path.

```
Route 1:  Gzipped file on SFTP --> unzip --> local directory
Route 2:  local directory --> process stuff --> Kafka
```

If route 2 has problems or falls behind in its work, I don't want route 1 to fill up the local directory. How can I limit the total number of files sitting in local dir waiting to be processed?

(if it was a single route I may be able to `throttle()` easier, but are there other options to look at the overall picture of multiple routes?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement a  custom `RoutePolicy` where you check the number of files in that directory and if its bigger than X then suspend the route, and resume it again if its lower than X.

See more details at the Camel docs: http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html

You can look at the existing `ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy` how its implemented for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks! The `ThrottlingInFlightRoutePolicy` code was extremely helpful, especially extending RoutePolicySupport as a base class.  Rather than checking the filesystem for a file count, I ended up checking the InFlightRepository to get a count of how many are in progress on Route 2. Either way, this opens up a lot of possibilities.  
P.S.  It was great to meet you on your tour of Minneapolis last month!

Comment: Ah good to hear you found a good solution. I had a great time in Minneapolis, and it was a milestone for me to walk across the Mississippi river. Did not know it started this far up the USA. Also didn't expect to see so many sky bridges in the city, amazing to know there is a 13 mile long maze of those to connect all the buildings. Always a pleasure spreading the word about Apache Camel.